# Wireshark capture only TCP packets with the RST flag set

Tags: tcp, wireshark, packet-analysis

I'm quite new to networking and I got stuck while reading "Practical Packet Analysis: Using Wireshark to Solve...".

On page 61 it is written:

> A common scenario is to capture only  TCP packets with the RST flag
>   set.  We will cover TCP extensively in Chapte r 6. For now, you just
>   need to know  that the flags of a TCP packet are located at offset
>   13. This is an interesting  field because it is collectively 1 byte in  size as the flags field, but each particular flag is identified by
>   a single bit within this byte. Multiple flags can be set 
>   simultaneously in a TCP packet, so we can’t efficiently filter by a
>   single tcp[13] value because several may  represent the RST bit being
>   set. Therefore, we must specify the location within the byte that we
>   wish to examine by appending that location to the current primitive
>   with a single ampersand ( & ). The RST flag is at the bit
>   representing the number 4 within this byte, and the fact that this
>   bit is set to 4 tells us that the flag is set. The filter looks like
>   this:

```
tcp[13] & 4 == 4
```

But when I look on TCP header on wiki, I see the RST flag is the 5th bit within the 13th byte (?)

[image]

My questions:

1. Why is it looking for the 4th bit within the 13 byte (`tcp[13] & 4`) ? Shouldn't be the 5th like marked in the picture?
2. Why is comparing the value of the flag with **4**? *TCP Contains 9 **1-bit** flags* Shouldn't the value of flag be either 0 or 1 ?
3. In order to check for URG flag, the book mentions filter `tcp[13] & 32 == 32` which I really don't get?

Thanks!

Comment: & seems to be the "bitwise logical and" operator.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The RST flag is at the bit representing the number 4 within this byte

refers to the numerical value of bit 2 (2<sup>2</sup> = 4) - the bits are numbered 76543210 from MSB to LSB with the numerical values 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1.

In the same manner, URG is bit 5 and 2<sup>5</sup> = 32.

Comment: Great, now that makes sense! So if I want to read flag NS I would say tcp[12] & 0 == 1 ? Can you also tell me why is comparing the flag with the numerical value (question 2), shouldn't be 0 or 1 ?

Comment: Anything `& 0` is always 0 - bit 0 has value 1 (2^0), so you use `tcp[12] & 1 != 0`. When you mask bits out with bitwise and (`&`), you clear all the other, the bit value is preserved -> test for bit 7: `tcp[12] & 128 != 0` or `tcp[12] & (1<<7) != 0`.

Comment: The Internet was designed for a military contract, and they required bits to be numbered 1 to N, starting from the MSB. That's the bit numbering in the Internet publications, such as RFCs. Everyone else uses powers-of-2, with the LSB having bit number 0 (ie, 2^0) and counting upwards towards the MSB. This is the bit numbering the programmers of tcpdump used.